# how to make sure that a child component gives value to parent component before it is destroyed in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

i want to make sure that @output of a child component (basically an eventemitter) has passed the value to parent component before it is getting destroyed.

Will giving the event emitter on Ondestroy() a good practise.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: An `EventEmitter` should emit data whenever the respective value changes, not just at the end of the components lifetime. This sounds like an XY-problem here. Could you please add some more details to clarify why you want or (think to) need this?